Why I am not able to make a comment in different questions?

Possible Duplicate:
Why can't some questions be commented on? 

Why I am not able to make a comment in different questions?
I though it is possible, but now i feel it is not. 

50 reputation is required to comment anywhere. You can always comment on your own questions and answers.
